# Strange behaviour when assigning list value to key in dictionary in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm having trouble to udnerstand what I did wrong in my simple code. I've found a "solution" but i would like to understand "why" :)
In general i'm doing a simple "group by" using the dictionary and lists.
When I assign to a key a value that is a 2 element list, the first element(value) in that dictionary, is splitted into two seperate values, all other value behave properly - are 2 elements list.

So I had 4 values when the dictionary was printed.

```
1301
425
['979', '340']
['1301', '977']
```

But I was able to fix this to have 3 pair values - the desired outcome:

```
['1301', '425']
['979', '340']
['1301', '977']
```

As I said i was able to fix this issue using the `.setdefault()` method to assign the first element insted of simple assigment but I don't understand why does it make a difference.
Here is my code, all other aspects of the class are working properly or will work properly in the "future" :):D

```
import os
import copy

from pathlib import Path

class ManageSettings:    
    def __init__(self, record_or_not = False,config_path = ".\\settings\\"):
        self.to_record       = record_or_not
        self.ini_path        = config_path + "\\position_settings.ini" # file path for settings
        path_to_save = Path(config_path)
        path_to_save.mkdir(exist_ok=True)
        self.__position_list = {}
    def save_or_load (self, sequence = 0):
            if(self.to_record):            
                pass                            
            else:
                self.load_settings()

    def save_settings(self, sequence = 0):
        with open(self.ini_path, 'w') as file_writter:
            for posXY in self.position_list:
                file_writter.write("{};{};{}\n".format(sequence, posXY[0], posXY[1]))

    def load_settings(self):
        with open(self.ini_path, 'r') as file_reader:
            sequence_dict = {}            
            for line_XY in file_reader:
                sequence, posX, posY = line_XY.strip().split(";")
                XYposList = list((posX, posY))
                print(XYposList)
                if not sequence in sequence_dict:
```

Here is the part that if changed will print a different result

```
                    # sequence_dict.setdefault(sequence,[]).append( XYposList)
                    sequence_dict[sequence] = XYposList
```

```
            else:        
                sequence_dict[sequence].append( XYposList)            # self.position_list = sequence_dict
        print ('in  class')
        for values in sequence_dict.values():
            print (values)
        self.position_list = sequence_dict
@property
def position_list(self):
    return self.__position_list
@position_list.setter
def position_list(self, position_list):
    self.__position_list = position_list
```

This is how can you simply test the class, of course if you have the ini file :)

```
testClas = ManageSettings(False)
testClas.save_or_load()
print("outside the class")
for  value in testKlas.position_list.values():
    # print (len(value))
    for test in value:
        print (test)
```

Edit: Hi, here is the content of the ini file

```
0;1301;425
0;979;340
0;1301;977
```

Comment: Can you share whats in the file you're opening and reading the lines into the dictionary?

Comment: Not related to the problem, but `list((posX, posY))` can be written as simply `[posX, posY]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
sequence_dict[sequence] = XYposList
```

should be:

```
sequence_dict[sequence] = [XYposList]
```

The values in `sequence_dict` are supposed to be 2-dimensional lists. But when you're creating the first value, you're not putting it in a list, you're just using `XYPostList` as the list. Then subsequent `append()` calls append to that list. So you start with

```
['1301', '425']
```

and the next line appends `['979', '340']` to that, resulting in

```
['1301', '425', ['979', '340']]
```

But what you want is for the initial value to be:

```
[['1301', '425']]
```

and then it becomes

```
[['1301', '425'], ['979', '340']]
```